# jq: Cannot index array with string

Tags: json, jq

I have the following in a file (which I will call "myfile"):

```
[{
    "id": 123,
    "name": "John",
    "aux": [{
        "abc": "random",
        "def": "I want this"
    }],
    "blah": 23.11
}]
```

I could parse it if the file did not have the first `[` and last `]` as follows:

```
$ cat myfile | jq -r '.aux[] | .def'
I want this
$
```

but with the `[` and `]` I get:

```
$ cat myfile | jq -r '.aux[] | .def'
jq: error: Cannot index array with string
```

How can I deal with the `[` and `]` using jq? (I'm sure I could parse them off with a different tool but I want to learn correct usage of jq.

Comment: I reread the question several times to get the idea and then realized that it's asked in a very bad way. There is basically a logical error in the story itself. Xu Wang says:  "I can parse it without <something>" and then immediately uses that something! What the heck? So what's the difference between the first and the second case? Could you please fix the question? Please also verify code highlighting. For some reason both pieces are highlighted differently so it's hard to see that the code is the same.

Comment: I tried to edit it myself but just got: "Suggested edit queue is full", whatever that means.

Comment: @Onkeltem indeed it was confusing. I am sorry. I made an edit to specify that the `[` and `]` refer to the first `[` in the file and the last `]` in the file.

Comment: The question talks of "parsing" it differently, as if the brackets were not there, but jq is all about following JSON standard, requiring these to be parsed as arrays. The answer instead is about looking up values differently, adjusted for the arrays presence.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

It should be:

```
jq '.[].aux[].def' file.json
```

`.[]` iterates over the outer array, `.aux[]` then iterates over the the `aux` array of every node and `.def` prints their `.def` property.

This will output:

```
"I want this"
```

If you want to get rid of the double quotes pass `-r` (`--raw`) to `jq`:

```
jq -r '.[].aux[].def' file.json
```

Output:

```
I want this
```

Comment: Good answer, thanks for the -r tip too for removing the quotes, super handy.