# I cannot get jq to give me the value I'm looking for.

Tags: json, bash, curl, jq

I'm trying to use jq to get a value from the JSON that cURL returns.

This is the JSON cURL passes to jq (and, FTR, I want jq to return "VALUE-I-WANT" without the quotation marks):

```
[  
   {  
      "success":{  
         "username":"VALUE-I-WANT"
      }
   }
]
```

I initially tried this:

```
jq ' . | .success | .username'
```

and got

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "success"
```

I then tried a bunch of variations, with no luck.

With a bunch of searching the web, I found [this SE entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543829/jq-cannot-index-array-with-string), and thought it might have been my saviour (spoiler, it wasn't). But it led me to try these:

```
jq -r '.[].success.username'
jq -r '.[].success'
```

They didn't return an error, they returned "null". Which may or may not be an improvement.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here? And why it's wrong?

Comment: `jq -r '.[].success.username` works properly with your example, whether using jq 1.3, jq 1.4, jq 1.5 or the current "master" version.

Answer (score 3):

You need to *pipe* the output of `.[]` into the next filter.

```
jq -r '.[] | .success.username' tmp.json
```

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**

```
# Extract .success.username from ALL array elements.
# .[] enumerates all array elements
# -r produces raw (unquoted) output
jq -r '.[].success.username' file.json

# Extract .success.username only from the 1st array element.
jq -r '.[0].success.username' file.json
```

---

**Your input is an *array*, so in order to access its *elements* you need `.[]`**, the [array/object-value iterator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters) (as the name suggests, it can also enumerate the *properties* of an *object*):

Just `. |` sends the input (`.`) array *as a whole* through the pipeline, and an array only has *numerical* indices, so the attempt to index (access) it with `.success.username` fails.

Thus, simply replacing `. |` with `.[] |` in your original attempt, combined with `-r` to get *raw* (unquoted output), should solve your problem, as shown in [chepner's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43553367/45375).

However, [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak) points out that since at least `jq 1.3` (current as of this writing is `jq 1.5`) you don't strictly need a *pipeline*, as demonstrated in the commands at the top.
So the 2nd command in your question *should* work with your sample input, unless you're using an older version.

Comment: I am probably going to just delete my answer; I never noticed that `.[].success` *should* work.